# objective c block that waits for another delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, watchkit

I have a watchkit app that calls a viewcontroller on an iphone app.  I have a delegate for a network connection.  I'm trying to use a block so that I don't tightly couple my AppDelegate and my view controller too closely.  How can I notify my block when the delegate is finished?

ViewController.m

```
-(void)getWatchDataWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL gotData))completion{
   [self setUpAppForWatch];
   completion(YES);
}

-(void)finishedMessageParse:(NSMutableData *)messageData{
   //the delegate is finish tell the block completion is done.

}

-(void)setUpAppForWatch{
   [network call];
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)
(NSDictionary *))reply{

[vc getWatchDataWithCompletion:^(BOOL gotData){
    if (gotData){
       //I'm done reply dictionary
       reply(@{@"data":serlizedData})
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add new property in viewcontroller:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void(^completion)(BOOL gotData);


-(void)getWatchDataWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL gotData))completion{
   [self setUpAppForWatch];
   self.completion = completion;
}

-(void)finishedMessageParse:(NSMutableData *)messageData{
    if (self.completion){
        self.completion(YES);
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case it is possible that your completion block will not be called never.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

There're three possible ways.

;tldr - refer to the third one. Else - read everything, it might be useful.

**First one**

Use private serial queue for performing tasks of `finished...` method and your block. It will suffice you in case, if `finished...` always called **before** block. If not - take a look at the **Second one**

Use private `@property dispatch_queue_t privateSerialQueue;` of View Controller.

```
privateSerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("PrivateQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

Than, use it like this

```
-(void)getWatchDataWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL gotData))completion{
    [self setUpAppForWatch];
    dispatch_async(privateSerialQueue, ^(){
       completion(YES);
    });
}

-(void)finishedMessageParse:(NSMutableData *)messageData{
    dispatch_sync(privateSerialQueue, ^(void){
            //Here goes whatever you need to do in this method before block start
    });
    //the delegate is finish tell the block completion is done.
}
```

**Second one**

Take a look at dispatch_semaphore_t. Make it a public property of your View Controler

`@property (readonly) dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore`

Create it with starting value 0. It will let you wait in case your block runs before delegate `finished...` method and run immediately, if `finished` has already completed before block. Like this

```
self.semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
```

Then you can use it this way

```
-(void)finishedMessageParse:(NSMutableData *)messageData{
  //the delegate is finish tell the block completion is done.
  dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
}

[vc getWatchDataWithCompletion:^(BOOL gotData){
    if (gotData){
       //I'm done reply dictionary
       dispatch_semaphore_wait(vc.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
       reply(@{@"data":serlizedData})
}];
```

**Third one**

Came to my mind while writing the two above =) 
Some kind of combination of previous two

Use *private* property of your view controller 
`@property (readonly) dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore`

Initialize it the same way, as in the second (with starting value 0)

```
self.semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
```

And use it privately like this

```
-(void)getWatchDataWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL gotData))completion{
    [self setUpAppForWatch];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    completion(YES);
}

-(void)finishedMessageParse:(NSMutableData *)messageData{
  //the delegate is finish tell the block completion is done.
  dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore);
}
```

P. S. Hope, it helps you to get to the point. Feel free to ask anything not clear